# How to use wordpress update_option() function to modify medium_large image deafault's width

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In recent wordpress versions, a new default intermediate size, "medium_large", has been added to better take advantage of responsive image support. The new size is 768px wide by default, with no height limit.

The medium_large size is not included in the UI when selecting an image to insert in posts, nor are included UI to change the image size from the media settings page. However, developers can modify the width of this new size using the update_option() function, similar to any other default image size.

Usage:

```
<?php update_option( $option, $new_value, $autoload ); ?>
```

Considering I have already tried to edit default medium_large image size through the following code in functions.php file WITHOUT success, may you please help me building the code through update_option, as explained above?

```
function filter_image_resize_dimensions( $payload, $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop ) {
if ( $orig_h > 200 ) {
    $new_w = 200;
    $new_h = auto;
}

return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, (int) $new_w, (int) $new_h, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );
```

}
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'filter_image_resize_dimensions', 10, 6 );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter `max_srcset_image_width` is not made to change the max width of the image size, but the max width of the srcset when using `wp_calculate_image_srcset()`.

To change the sizes if the WordPress predefined images, you need to use `image_resize_dimensions`, you can read all the details [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/image_resize_dimensions)

UPDATE 
From you given code, here is some correction about it

```
function filter_image_resize_dimensions( $payload, $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop ) {
    if ( $orig_h === 300 ) {
        $new_w = 200; // you are checking for height and setting width ??
        $new_h = $orig_h; // you must define it to return a value, but here there's no change... 
    }

    return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, (int) $new_w, (int) $new_h, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );
}
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'filter_image_resize_dimensions', 10, 6 );
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I retried this way, but failed again: function filter_image_resize_dimensions( $max_width, $size_array ) {
if ( $size_array[0] === 300 ) {
$max_width = 200;
}

return $max_width;
}
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'filter_image_resize_dimensions', 10, 2 );

Comment: The parameters​ for the callback function are not the same as your previous function, read the provide example on my link, there's no $size_array, but $orig_h , $orig_w. Change your conditional statement and change the filter max args to 6 and it should work.

Comment: if ( $orig_h > 200 ) {
        $new_w = 200;
        $new_h = auto;
    }
 --- is this code correct?

Comment: (I want to set width resized to 200 and height auto but proportionally risized basing on resized width)

Comment: It depends on your theme (or a plugin), when you upload an image, WordPress save differents sizes, accordling to the declared image_size, fired with the add_image_size() function, you can easily remove any image_size with the function remove_image_size (but you need to find its slug to remove it properly), and you can also modifiy the add_image_size parameter via filter.

Comment: Thank you so much. May you answer me for a last time? Need to know what's wrong on the current code I edited. I tried to set it to work if original height is higher than 200 (taking all cases in my situation) to edit the image making its width 200 and its height auto based on proportional resizing. Is not working this way, maybe I put some wrong symbol? Thanks again.